# Assembly Segmentation Fault on STR

Tags: assembly, arm

I want to make an array of 0 - 9, but I keep on getting seg fault on str r1, [r0, r1, lsl #2].
str r1, [r0, r1, lsl #2] is a requirement and I'll have to use that format for str and ldr. Any help is appreciated.

```
main:
  push {fp, lr}
  add fp, sp, #4

  mov r0, #0x20000000
  mov r1, #0

loop:
  cmp r1, #10
  bge done

  str r1, [r0, r1, lsl #2]
  add r1, r1, #1
  b loop

done:
  sub sp, fp, #4
  pop {fp, pc}
```

Comment: Well, is the memory at `0x20000000` writable?

Comment: It's just a random memory location. Is the memory not writable by default?

Comment: Generally not. Allocate a static array in your `.data` section and load its address. Heck, 0x20000000 might not even exist :)

Comment: If you're building this `main` into a Linux executable, you can look at `/proc/<PID>/maps` where <PID> is the process ID of the running program to see what parts of virtual address space are mapped for a simple program like this that just links against libc.  (e.g. start it under a debugger so it stops at a breakpoint, then use `ps` or `pidof my_program` to find it).

Comment: @FuzzyStussy No, it isn't even guaranteed that a random address is even RAM area.